# Displaying a range of data from mySQL based on a single selected value?

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements

I'm very new to server side programming and I've been having trouble wrapping my head around this:

I have a data that essentially breaks down into 7 groups, each having a title and specific ID # and each group has a list of subtext associated with it.

For example if the user selects ID #3 I know that I need to display ID #4-10.

How would I select a specific range of ID #s in the query?

```
$sql = "SELECT /*course title*/
A.title as course_title, 
/*objective text*/
B.body, 
/*competency text*/
C.title,
/*child subcompetency*/
E.child_competency_id


FROM hsdb45_med_admin.course as A,
db.objective as B,
db.competency as C,
db.course_objective_competency as D,
db.competency_relationship as E
WHERE
C.competency_id = ? AND
B.objective_id = D.objective_id AND
C.competency_id = D.competency_id
/*conditional statement here???*/
```

Comment: look `between` in [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)... like `where C.competency BETWEEN 4 AND 10`

Comment: How about `C.competency_id >= 4 AND C.competency_id <= 10`?

Comment: I've looked at between but is there a way to set the 4 and 10 to be selected based on the value of C.competency_id?  There are 7 potential ranges so it would have to be BETWEEN X AND Y

Comment: I don't understand the question. However I'd like to give the advice to start with up-to-date join syntax, e.g. `INNER JOIN d ON d.objective_id = b.objective_id`. Maybe that could already clarify things.

Comment: Its clear by your question what determines your lower bound (3+ next record = 4) but what determines your upper bound?

Comment: You also fail to show how all of the tables join.  The query as it stands would create a cartesian product because you dont constrain tables `A` or `E` at all.  What are those constraints?

Comment: Unfortunately there's no clear definition.  These database and tables were not created by our group and are, from what I've heard and seen, poorly designed.  I know the IDs of the 7 main groups (i.e. 3, 11, 19, 28) and the sub-groups are between those ranges, sequentially, but there's no telling where they start and end without looking at the database and mapping it out.

Comment: Then put that mapping in a new table, to start out. That way you can JOIN this new table to obtain what you need.

Comment: @Frazz makes a good suggestion.  If you dont know how to find your ranges, there is no use trying to build a query to display them.  Build a reference table, then join to it using `between`

Comment: Thanks for the advice - sounds like an easier route.  Learning!